# KVM guest low cpu usage while host OS reports very high cpu load

Tags: virtualization, cpu-usage, linux-kvm

I am facing this issue.
On a 18.04 host OS, i have one KVM guest with same image.
Host has 4 physical (8 threads) cores.I am giving 2 cores in the VM.

The problem is when the guest OS is having a little cpu load like 10%.
Then the host OS reports like 100% in 2 cores.
I tried the perf top and see that the read_tsc kernel call is taking much of the load.Right after follows the vmx_allowed_interrupt.
I tried everything, changing configuration of the domain xml,for virtual disk(some people were helped with this),but no luck.

Any ideas perhaps,coz i am running out.Thanks a lot.